# C++ variadic function template in std::functional

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, std-function

basically I want to integrate a multi-dimensional integral with this recursion.
But the problem itself is a general one. It's not specific for integration.

```
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

double f(double x,double y,double z){
    return x+y+z+1;
}

//Base
double redDim(std::function<double(double)> &f){
    return f(0); //a silly integrator for testing
}
// Recursion
template<typename Tfirst=double, typename... Trest>
auto redDim(std::function<double(Tfirst first,Trest... rest)> &f){
    return redDim([=](Trest... R){return redDim([=](double x){return f(x,R...);});});
}

int main(){
    std::cout<<redDim(f)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, compiler says:

```
c:\C++\templateTutorial\templateTut.cpp: In function 'int main()':
c:\C++\templateTutorial\templateTut.cpp:24:19: error: no matching function for call to 'redDim(double (&)(double, double, double))'
     cout<<redDim(f)<<endl;
                   ^
c:\C++\templateTutorial\templateTut.cpp:12:8: note: candidate: 'double redDim(std::function<double(double)>&)'
 double redDim(std::function<double(double)> &f){
        ^~~~~~
c:\C++\templateTutorial\templateTut.cpp:12:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'double(double, double, double)' to 'std::function<double(double)>&'
c:\C++\templateTutorial\templateTut.cpp:17:6: note: candidate: 'template<class Tfirst, class ... Trest> auto redDim(std::function<double(Tfirst, Trest ...)>&)'
 auto redDim(std::function<double(Tfirst first,Trest... rest)> &f){
      ^~~~~~
c:\C++\templateTutorial\templateTut.cpp:17:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
c:\C++\templateTutorial\templateTut.cpp:24:19: note:   mismatched types 'std::function<double(Tfirst, Trest ...)>' and 'double(double, double, double)'
     cout<<redDim(f)<<endl;
                   ^
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

So why is the type of `f` not matching the requirements of `redDim()` ?
Thus I can't even test, if my method works.
I hope you could help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lambda of a lambda : the function is not captured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461538/lambda-of-a-lambda-the-function-is-not-captured)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function pointer is not a `std::function`.

Template argument deduction does not do any type conversions, other than a few to-base cases.

Add a `redim( double(*f)(Args...) )` template that calls the std function one.

```
template<class...Args>
auto redDim( double(*f)(Args...) {
  return redDim( std::function<double(Args...)>{ f } );
}
```

and it should work.

This can deduce the signature of the function pointer.  It then explicitly converts to a `std::function`, which then matches your other `redim` functions.

You do have to explicitly convert your other lambdas to `std::function`s:

```
// Recursion
template<typename Tfirst, typename... Trest>
auto redDim(std::function<double(Tfirst first,Trest... rest)> f){
  return redDim(
    std::function<double(Trest...)>{
      [=](Trest... R){
        return redDim(
          std::function<double(double)>{
            [=](double x){return f(x,R...);}
          }
        );
      }
    }
  );
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0cddd479c5bbb14).

Also change the argument for the last `redDim` to `std::function<double(double)>` (not a reference).  Alternatively, a `const&`.

Comment: Now the next error is:

required from 'auto redDim(double (*)(Args ...)) [with Args = {double, double, double}]'  
**error:** no matching function for call to 'redDim(redDim(std::function<double(Tfirst, Trest ...)>) [with Tfirst = double; Trest = {double, double}]::<lambda(double, double)>)'
  return redDim([&](Trest... rest){return redDim([&](double x){return f(x,rest...);});});

Comment: @Babalion Live example added.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Yakk - Adam Nevraumont's answer, the following code should compile:

```
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

double f(double x,double y,double z){
    return x+y+z+1;
}

//Base
double redDim(const std::function<double(double)> &f){
    return f(0); //a silly integrator for testing
}
// Recursion
template<typename Tfirst=double, typename... Trest>
auto redDim(const std::function<double(Tfirst first,Trest... rest)> &f) {

    return redDim(
    std::function<double(Trest...)>{
        [=](Trest... R)->double{return redDim([=](double x){return f(x,R...);});}});
}

template<class...Args>
auto redDim( double(*f)(Args...)) {
  return redDim( std::function<double(Args...)>{ f } );
}

int main(){
    std::cout<<redDim(f)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As Yakk already pointed out, `std::function` and a function pointer don't have the same type. Please note that I've also changed the argument type of `redDim` to `const std::function<...> &)`. You could also pass `rvalue` references using the `&&` syntax.